# How to change color of edge with iPhone on my website

Tags: html, css

When I'm checking my website on my iPhone XS the borders are white and that doesn't fit with my website. How can I change that? 
On the image on the left and right site you can see the white edges. Can I change that color?

[border on iPhone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMgLt.jpg)

This is my viewport meta

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

Comment: What's your <meta name="viewport".... tag in index.html?

Comment: PLEASE post the code so we can help you

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

Comment: That's unlikely to be a border -- it's more likely that you've set a fixed width on your page and your phone is wider than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'll use the background color for the `html` or `body` tag, so this should work:

```
body { background-color: DeepPink; }
```

You can also set `viewport-fit=cover` in your `viewport` tag to have it fill in those areas with your HTML completely. If you do this, though, you may have to tweak padding so the important bits of your page don't get obscured by the notch; Apple provides [some specific ways](https://www.icscreative.com/2017/11/dr-strangehump/) to [adjust to  the available space](https://css-tricks.com/the-notch-and-css/).